# Finding Z-score from area centered on 0 using R

Tags: r, normal-distribution

Question in a textbook: find the Z-score for 80% of the area centered on 0.
I know how to look it up in a table - the answer is +/- 1.28
Does anyone know how to get this out from R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `qnorm` function, you can get the z-score such that the area to the left of z is whatever you enter for the argument p.  If you're looking for the middle 80%, then the positive z-score is the number such that 90% is to the left of it--80% in the middle plus 10% in the left tail.

```r
> qnorm(0.9)
[1] 1.281552
```

Comment: Thanks, Lynn, much appreciated.